# Why is this generics array creation not working as expected?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code where I'm creating an array and trying to store objects in it. At run time, I get an `ArrayStoreException`.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class GenericsArrayCreation<T> {

    public static <T> void Test(T[] A){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(A.getClass(), A.length);
        for(int i = 0;i<temp.length;i++){
            temp[i] = A[i];
            System.out.println(temp[i].toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] strs = {"a", "b", "c"};
        GenericsArrayCreation.Test(strs);
    }
}
```

I somehow understand that this is because of the statement

```
T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(A.getClass(), A.length);
```

Why is this wrong? `A.getClass()` at runtime returns a `String`, so `temp` should be an array of strings. In that case, why is the assignment `temp[i] = A[i]` not working?

Comment: Have you confirmed (with a debugger or `print` statement) that `A.getClass()` is `String`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `A` is `java.lang.String[]`, rather than `java.lang.String`.

You want the component type of the array, rather than the array type itself.

Use this line instead:

```
T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(A.getClass().getComponentType(), A.length);
```

and the code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `temp.getClass()` - it's an array of arrays, `T[][]`. You will want `Class.getComponentType`.

Comment: No. The doc says: If componentType represents an array class, the number of dimensions of the new array is equal to the sum of dimensions.length and the number of dimensions of componentType. In this case, the component type of the new array is the component type of componentType.

Comment: @nes1983 What? *"Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null."*

Comment: Honestly, I think this API sucks.

Answer (score 0):

your `A.getClass()` returns a `String` array and not `String`, thats why you are getting `ArrayStoreException`.